# How could I adapt this query to work over multiple years?

Tags: sql, vistadb

This query pulls data from a VistaDB and produces info on the number of courses started in each month of the year from people in different countries.

```
Select c.CountryName As Country,
  Count (case When Month( ch.CourseStarted ) = 1 Then 1 End) As Jan19,
  Count (case when Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 2 Then 1 End) as Feb19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 3 Then 1 End) as Mar19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 4 Then 1 End) as Apr19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 5 Then 1 End) as May19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 6 Then 1 End) as Jun19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 7 Then 1 End) as Jul19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 8 Then 1 End) as Aug19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 9 Then 1 End) as Sep19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 10 Then 1 End) as Oct19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 11 Then 1 End)as Nov19,
  Count (case When Month(ch.CourseStarted  ) = 12 Then 1 End) as Dec19
From Country As c
  Inner Join CourseHistory As ch On c.Oid = ch.Country
Where (ch.CourseStarted >= '2019-01-01' And
       ch.CourseStarted <= '2019-12-31')
Group By c.CountryName
Order by c.CountryName;
```

My question is would it be possible to make this semi-dynamic so that if I were to make the final date in the where clause `'2022-12-31'` I could get a rafft of colums for each month of each year?

Comment: Add `Year( ch.CourseStarted)` to SELECT clause and GROUP BY clause, remove WHERE clause, and see what happens.

Comment: @jarlh  That's close to what I want thank you but its producing a row for each individual course take over the period, Adding Distinct does not help in this case unfortunately.